# How can I put the results of TrigReduce function into a more convenient form?

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, printing

```
a1 D11 Cos[n x] + a0 a1 D11 Cos[n x] + 1/2 a1 a3 D11 Cos[n x] + 
 1/2 a2 a4 D11 Cos[n x]
```

.......for example this expression can be written like ('expression') * Cos[n x]`but`TrigReduce` gives it in multiple expressions. How can I overcome this problem??

Comment: `TrigFactor` (or `Factor` for that matter) factors out your `Cos[n x]`.

Comment: @ChipHurst.... I reviewed my question. Please reply with an answer.

Comment: I think my original comment stands. `TrigFactor` and `Factor` both factor out the `Cos[n x]`.

Comment: @ChipHurst.... I have a large trigonometric expression,  so can I Factor out different Cos[n x] and Sin[n x] multiply expressions so that it will be easy to copy each expression corresponding to each trigonometric term. I just want each trigonometric factor should be printed out differently.

Comment: You might want to try `Collect[]` here.

Comment: Collect [ ] does not work properly on FortranForm expression.